# Reset/Flush Telephony Data Statistics

Tags: adb, telephony

I'm working with a company that uses Android architecture and an LTE modem for an IoT device. I am working on some software tests that ensure the modem is internally connected properly using

```
dumpsys telephony.registry | grep -i mSignalStrength
```

and

```
dumpsys telephony.registry | grep -i mDataConnectionLinkProperties
```

I have been able to test this with no antennas attached (to get a worst-case baseline) and with antennas attached. The expected behavior is to see `-1` for most fields when the antennas are disconnected and other values when they are attached. I have run into some issues in the case of the antennas starting off attached to the modem, then removing them after checking the telephony data (simulating loose antenna connection that comes undone after an initial check). When this happens, I don't always see a decline in rsrp/rsrq even though there are no antennas.

Is there a way to flush/reset the telephony data? Is that the best way to go about testing this? Any help would be appreciated.